# jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <builtin>, line 1:

Tags: jq

I'm having trouble running `jq` from my linux host. I don't understand why.

```sh
$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 5.3.8-200.fc30.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Oct 29 14:46:22 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

モ cat /etc/redhat-release
Fedora release 30 (Thirty)

$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

$ file $(which jq)
/usr/bin/jq: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=aca83aa7ecf04e5385c4cc94657cfc9ea1df86d3, stripped

$ jq --version
jq-1.6

$ echo '{}' | jq .
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <builtin>, line 1:
ELF
jq: 1 compile error
```

Comment: Could you tell us what happens after executing: `export LANG=C.UTF-8`

Comment: ```bash
$ echo $LANG
en_CA.UTF-8

$ export LANG=C.UTF-8

$ echo '{}' | jq .
{}
```

Comment: @mokha To be on the safe side, consider inspect the data in 'hex': `hexdump <<< "echo '{}' | jq ."` (copy/paste the command line with the error). Might give a clue to encoding issue.

Comment: Does 'jq' works on the '{}', when you put it in a file: `jq . < file` ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you figure it out? For information, I've tried to install from repository, I've downloaded the binary, I've tried to compile that myself and I've installed from Conda.

```sh
$ hexdump -C file
00000000  7b 7d 0a                                          |{}.|
00000003
```
  
```sh
$ jq . < file
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <builtin>, line 1:
ELF
jq: 1 compile error
```

Comment: After exporting LANG, jq started functioning as expected for me.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I tried to use a `.jq` file with CR/LF line endings on Linux. Changing it to LF fixed the problem.